# Create conditional helper function in Node JS

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I have this code repeating at many places

```
const errors = validator.validationResult(req);
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.mapped() });
}
```

So I refactored it into a helper function. So I created this helper code

```
module.exports.validationErrorsHandler = (req, res, validator) => {
  const errors = validator.validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.mapped() });
  }
}
```

But I think it is wrong because it is doing a "return" statement in helper function only if a condition is true.

if I call it inside main code like this, it runs but then the code execution breaks

```
const helpers = require('../helpers')
helpers.validationErrorsHandler(req, res, validator)
```

Comment: Does your main code do anything with the value returned from it, or does `return` only affect control flow there?

Comment: It effects the control flow. So if it returns, then the rest of the code shouldn't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're conditionally returning, you'll have to put that logic in the main function, not (just) the helper function. You could have the helper function return the `res.status` call, then in the main code, see if the return value of the helper function exists. If so, return. Keep your helper function as is, but change your main code to:

```
const possibleErrorRes = helpers.validationErrorsHandler(req, res, validator);
if (possibleErrorRes) return;
```

Comment: I think it should be if (possibleErrorRes) return possibleErrorRes;

Comment: I asked in the comment, but you said it was there for control flow. If all it's there for is control flow, you don't need to return it.

Comment: Basically this makes the helper function useless as I can turn the original code also into 2 lines lolz

Comment: It's not possible to (possibly conditionally) return from a function except when directly inside that function. The only way to stop execution from an inner function would be to `throw` an error, and have a consumer `try`/`catch` it, but that's quite inelegant. If you want to use a helper function, this would be the way to do it. If you don't think it's worth it, that's up to you.

Comment: Agree. Thanks for your suggestion though. Makes things more clear :)